# how to generate a bitcoin address for each user that registers

Tags: blockchain, php, marketplace, forum

I'm working on a marketplace type website and i want a bitcoin address to be generated for each user that registers an account. this needs to be done in php with no javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running your own Bitcoind for JSON RPC calls via PHP then you can generate new address for each of your customers by this JSON Call command in PHP like this:

```
echo $wallet->getnewaddress();
```

This will echo the new address and stores it in wallet variable. Please refer to this doc https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list

I hope this helps.

Thanks